# linux c/c++ - weird if/else issue

Tags: c++, mysql, c, linux

I'm querying a mysql table which then loops through the results.

One of the fields has a value of "0" in it, so when I try the following it doesn't work!

```
while ((row2 = mysql_fetch_row(resultset2)) != NULL) {
    if (row2[2] != "0") {
        // the field has a value of 0, but it's still executing the code here!
    } else {
        // should be executing this code
    }
}
```

I know C/C++ is very strict when it comes variables (unlink php), but I can't figure this one out. Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: looks like you should be using string comparison rather than pointer comparison

Comment: I assume that row2 is holding on to some type of string.  Can you just print the value of row2[2] before the conditional?

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. Is ot C or is it C++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're comparing `row2[2]`, a pointer to `char`, with a pointer to the constant `char` array `"0"`.

Use `strcmp(row2[2], "0") != 0` (C solution), `std::string(row2[2]) != "0"` (C++ solution), or `atoi(row2[2]) != 0` if you know `row2[2]` is always the string representation of an integer (and cannot be a SQL `NULL` value).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare string literal like this :

```
if (row2[2] != "0") //wrong
```

Either you do this :

```
if (strcmp(row2[2], "0")) //correct
```

Or this:

```
if (std::string(row2[2]) != "0") //correct
```

---

For this particular case, when there is only one character you can also do this:

```
if (row2[2][0] != '0') //correct  - not the single quote around 0!
```