# How do I stop the thread function if it is ended in Python?

Tags: python

I have made small scraper which do follows:

1. Open the txt file and load the URLs for each line and then using soup request the url content
2. it look in the url content 'emails'
3. I want the bot stop once he use all the links from the `channel_links.txt` file opened to avoid do the task again over and over, how do I do that?

**MY SNIPPET CODE:**

```
import time
import os
import threading
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def rpsm_loop():
    global rps, rpm
    while True:
        initial = reqs
        time.sleep(1)
        rps = round((reqs - initial) / 60, 1)
        rpm = round(rps * 60, 1)

def scrapeEmails():
    global reqs, _lock, success, fails, rps, rpm

    with open(os.path.join("channel_links.txt"), "r") as f:
        for _count, line in enumerate(f):
            pass

        for x in range(_count):
            with open(os.path.join("channel_links.txt"), "r") as f:
                for line in f:
                    url = line.strip()
                    html = (url + "/about")
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(html, cookies={
                        'CONSENT': 'YES+cb.20221228-17-p0.en-GB+FX+{}'.format(random.randint(100, 999))},
                                                      proxies=proxies).text, "html.parser")

# here it do a job and write found emails in text but it doesnt want to stop once it gets the last link from **channel_links.txt**
if __name__ == "__main__":
    _lock = threading.Lock()
    reqs = 0
    success = 0
    fails = 0
    rpm = 0
    rps = 0

    threading.Thread(target=rpsm_loop).start()
    
    while True:
        if threading.active_count() < 10:
            try:
                time.sleep(1.5)
                threading.Thread(target=thread_starter).start()
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: add your thread definition code

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've added 'for x in range(_count):' but it keeps looping

Comment: The code is lacking the function `thread_starter` and the list `proxies`

Comment: @mnikley you can replace ThreadStarted with scrapeEmails definition because it is the same I only added few other functions and option what thread will start and list of proxies why? is it needed? I dont think so there is only a list of 5 private proxies which loads

Answer (score 1):

Glad you figured it out. For completion, you might want to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` for this task. After submitting all your tasks at once, you can define the number of tasks to be processed simultaneously with the `max_workers` argument. Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def fetch_data(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    # do some processing
    print(f"Thread finished for url: {url}")


# just some random stackoverflow questions
urls_to_process = [
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75133271",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058874",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057665",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057365",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096083",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096084",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409423",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408767",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408733",
]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    for url in urls_to_process:
        print("Submitting a new thread.. ")
        executor.submit(fetch_data, url)

    # wait until all threads are done
    executor.shutdown(wait=True)

print("All threads done!")
```

Comment: do you want to kill my brain? hahahah anyway yes thanks

Comment: sir could you pls help in this question I asked here because the person who answered works only half his solution and Im getting always the duplicate and I dont want to aks same question again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75132946/how-do-i-write-scraped-lines-in-txt-and-check-for-duplicate-before-it-writes-in/75133358?noredirect=1#comment132586574_75133358

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I'm answering my own question hahah I'm really learnign this python :)

> Source:
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/

So the fix was to PUT the `break` after I read on other topics here how to stop function, thanks again all who posted and tried to help me

```
if not line:
  break
```